# vim-LanguageTool and vim-grammarous not working

Tags: vim, vi, languagetool

I am using  VIM version 8.1.1401 on Debian Buster. I am pretty new to VIM (just few days ago I started using it) and trying to get some plugin which can detect the grammatical mistakes. After few google searches I found [vim-LanguageTool](https://github.com/dpelle/vim-LanguageTool) and [vim-grammarous](https://github.com/rhysd/vim-grammarous). There was little information regarding vim-grammarous's installation steps for newbies. Nonetheless, I finally got both of them working. I can see errors from these two. However, I am unable to correct or navigate between them. I am stuck on 'Scratch' windows. I can see some text suggesting few corrections and mistakes in that window but I am unable to understand how to use them. Can anyone explain it to me in layman's term how to use these plugins? I tried to check how to switch between buffers and scratch windows but none of those have worked.

Following is my `.vimrc` file (Comments are removed for brevity)

```
runtime! debian.vim

set nocompatible              
filetype off         
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim

call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'ervandew/supertab'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'dpelle/vim-LanguageTool'
Plugin 'SirVer/ultisnips'
Plugin 'lervag/vimtex'
Plugin 'honza/vim-snippets'
Plugin 'mtth/scratch.vim'

call vundle#end()            
filetype plugin indent on    


let g:ycm_key_list_select_completion = ['<C-n>', '<Down>']
let g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion = ['<C-p>', '<Up>']
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = '<C-n>'

if !exists('g:ycm_semantic_triggers')
    let g:ycm_semantic_triggers = {}
endif

let g:ycm_semantic_triggers.tex = g:vimtex#re#youcompleteme
let g:tex_flavor='latex'

syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
set showcmd     
set showmatch       

if filereadable("/etc/vim/vimrc.local")
  source /etc/vim/vimrc.local
endif

nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :exec '!python3' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
map <f2> :w<cr><leader>ll

autocmd VimLeave * call system("xsel -ib", getreg('+'))

noremap j gj
noremap k gk

:let g:languagetool_jar='/path/to/LanguageTool-4.7/languagetool-commandline.jar'
:let g:languagetool_lang='en-GB'
```

vim-grammarous was installed as shown in [this](http://www.comrite.com/wp/vim-grammar-check/) blog post.

<sup>*Note: I am re-posting this question from [other](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20719/vim-languagetool-and-vim-grammarous-not-working) SE site because I did not get any response from there and very limited exposure to the question.*</sup>

Comment: Have you read plugin's Readme? The section is called "Local mappings in the information window". Concerning window switching, read `:help windows`.

Comment: Please show us your .vimrc

Comment: @GiftZwergrapper Done

Comment: @Matt, Yes. Unfortunately, I could not understand it as I am learning it since just few days and not aware of lot of its concepts.

Comment: "Local mapping" means that the corresponding key works only when the plugin's window has keyboard focus (well, actually it's _buffer_ local, but it's not of a big difference in this case). Simply click inside that "information window" with a mouse and press '?'.

Comment: @Matt, I tried clicking inside scratch window, that did not do anything. Whatever keys I was pressing, were affecting original document.

Comment: Mouse support is probably not activated, try navigating to that buffer via keyboard instead of clicking.